# Bootstrap 4 grid columns not assuming max height

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap 4 to construct a grid of rows and columns. Mostly everything is laid out as I like it, except for the 3 columns on the bottom left area, which I cannot get to automatically grow to the maximum height of the row they are place within. I have added a border to every row and column for demonstration, and I've added a blue background to the columns that will not automatically resize to the full possible height. I've tried everything I can think of, and can't quite get the columns to automatically grow to the full height.

I will normally have `charts.js` charts in the 3 columns, and when they don't grow to fill the entire height of the column, the charts get squished and look bad. Any help would be extremely appreciated!

I've constructed a (hopefully) full codepen example here:

https://codepen.io/coldcoffeecup/pen/aGgpoV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Bootstrap's `row` comes with `display: flex`, unfortunately the columns do not. As such, if you simply want to make the blue squares expand to fill the full vertical space, all you need to do is add the following CSS:

```
#A {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

This can be seen working [**here**](https://codepen.io/Obsidian-Age/pen/gzNgrN).

```css
.hovereffect {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: default;
}

.hovereffect .overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .4s ease-in-out
}

.hovereffect img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s linear;
  transition: all .4s linear;
}

.hovereffect h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 17px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  -webkit-transform: translatey(-100px);
  -ms-transform: translatey(-100px);
  transform: translatey(-100px);
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  padding: 10px;
}

.hovereffect a.info {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  background-color: transparent;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  margin: 50px 0 0;
  padding: 7px 14px;
}

.hovereffect a.info:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff;
}

.hovereffect:hover img {
  -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

.hovereffect:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}

.hovereffect:hover h2,
.hovereffect:hover a.info {
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  -ms-transform: translatey(0);
  -webkit-transform: translatey(0);
  transform: translatey(0);
}

.hovereffect:hover a.info {
  -webkit-transition-delay: .2s;
  transition-delay: .2s;
}

.fullwidth {
  width: 100% !important;
}

.fullheight {
  height: 100% !important;
}

#A {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <link rel="icon" href="assets/images/favicon.ico">

  <title>Template</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  <link href="assets/css/starter-template.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/10.0.2/css/bootstrap-slider.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Dashboard</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" id="reportDropdown" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Account
                </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
          <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Account</button>
          <button class="dropdown-item" id="sign-out" type="button">Sign Out</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <main role="main" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="starter-template">
      <h1 class="display-4">Title</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-9 border" id="A">
          <div class="row border" id="A1">
            <div class="col-3 border">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="dropdown fullwidth">
                  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle fullwidth" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                        Type
                                    </button>
                  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#!">A</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#!">B</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#!">C</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row border" style="padding:5% 10% 5% 10%;">
                <div class="fullwidth">
                  <p class="lead text-muted text-center">
                    Slide 1
                  </p>
                </div>
                <input id="slider1" type="text" class="span2" value="" data-slider-min="10" data-slider-max="1000" data-slider-step="5" data-slider-value="[10,450]" />
              </div>
              <div class="row border" style="padding:5% 10% 5% 10%;">
                <div class="fullwidth">
                  <p class="lead text-muted text-center">
                    Slide 2
                  </p>
                </div>
                <input id="slider2" type="text" class="span2" value="" data-slider-min="10" data-slider-max="1000" data-slider-step="5" data-slider-value="[10,450]" />
              </div>
              <div class="row border" style="padding:5% 10% 5% 10%;">
                <div class="fullwidth">
                  <p class="lead text-muted text-center">
                    Slide 3
                  </p>
                </div>
                <input id="slider3" type="text" class="span2" value="" data-slider-min="10" data-slider-max="1000" data-slider-step="5" data-slider-value="[10,450]" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col border">
              A4
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row bg-primary d-flex flex-fill" id="A2">
            <div class="col-4 border">
              <canvas id="chart1"></canvas>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 border">
              <canvas id="chart2"></canvas>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 border">
              <canvas id="chart3"></canvas>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col border" id="B">
          <div class="row border">
            <ul class="list-group fullwidth">
              <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                A
                <span>
                                    <i class="fa fa-plus-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </span>
              </li>
              <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                B
                <span>
                                    <i class="fa fa-plus-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </span>
              </li>
              <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                C
                <span>
                                    <i class="fa fa-plus-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </span>
              </li>
              <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                D
                <span>
                                    <i class="fa fa-plus-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </span>
              </li>
              <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                E
                <span>
                                    <i class="fa fa-plus-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </span>
              </li>
              <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                F
                <span>
                                    <i class="fa fa-plus-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </span>
              </li>
              <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                G
                <span>
                                    <i class="fa fa-plus-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </span>
              </li>
              <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                H
                <span>
                                    <i class="fa fa-plus-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </span>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="row border">
            <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Enter a value" class="form-control" aria-label="Small" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm">
              <div class="input-group-append">
                <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" type="button">Add</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row border">
            <ul class="list-group fullwidth">
              <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                I
                <span><i class="fa fa-minus-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
              </li>
              <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                J
                <span><i class="fa fa-minus-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
              </li>
              <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                K
                <span><i class="fa fa-minus-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="row border" style="padding:3%">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary fullwidth">Done</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </main>
  <!-- /.container -->

  <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
  <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script>
    window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../../../assets/js/vendor/jquery-slim.min.js"><\/script>')
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/vendor/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/10.0.2/bootstrap-slider.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/slider.js" rel="stylesheet"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/chartCode.js" rel="stylesheet"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/create.js" rel="stylesheet"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you so much for the quick answer. Very much appreciated!